# Can we assign a tag to an <include> statement

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm in the process of transitioning from an unwieldy view layout, with lots of repetition of basic view groups, to one where each type of view group has its own layout, which I then include in each layout.

Each view group has a control element (e.g. checkbox) with a particular view id (using `@+id/...`), and an associated text view (label) which refers to a string id (using `@string/...`).

By far the easiest (and most bug-free) way to transition (at least in a first stage) would be to use search (with regexp) and replace the view groups with an include, but since each view group has two different bits of info (view id, and string id), I need to replace this with an include that has both bits of information, so that I can put the view back together programmatically and assign the right text to the text view.

The plan was to end up with something like:

```
<include layout="@layout/setting_switch"
    android:tag="some_string_name"
    android:id="@+id/some_view_group" />
```

In the above, the tag `some_string_name` can be used to fetch the right string for the text view in the included layout, and the id `some_view_group` can be used to find the checkbox in the included layout using a two-level `findViewById(R.id.some_view_group).findViewById(R.id.generic_switch)`.

BUT it seems that `findViewById(R.id.some_view_group).getTag()` (which I want to use to fetch the string with that name) returns `null`.

Is there any way to specify something like a tag directly in the XML, to make my plan work?

(BTW lint doesn't complain about my use of `android:tag` in the above, which made me think at first it might be OK... maybe I'm just not using the right method to read the tag back?)

Comment: Have you considered using a [Compound Control?](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components#compound)? Each included group would be its own compound control with whatever attributes you would like.

Comment: @Cheticamp looks interesting... that may well be the way to go.

Comment: @Cheticamp yes, I've now implemented what I want using a compound control, and it's working perfectly... in fact, better than I expected because (as you of course know) it's possible to be even more structured with a compound control by providing top-level setters and getters for the underlying constituent components... makes everything much neater.  If you post an Answer I'll mark it as accepted... it would be interesting still to know if it is possible to specify a tag for an include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you will be able to get the value of a tag attribute transferred to an included layout as you wish. See [Use the <include> tag](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Include).

> You can also override all the layout parameters (any android:layout_* attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in the  tag.

The tag parameter is not of the right type to get transferred.

In any case, a [Compound Control](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components#compound) will be a better option. It is a standard type of implementation which will be more maintainable than the tag option you are looking at and will do all the things you want and more. With a compound control, it is easy to over nest view groups. Take a look also at the [merge tag](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Merge).